# federatedSignIn with aws-amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using 'Auth' from aws-amplify to authenticate user. But when I logged in successful with Google account using federatedSingIn. I turn off wifi and turn on again, now Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() return error 'no current user'. I want to know that whether it is my bug in amplify configuration or it is a way Amplify works. If it is my bug, please help me fix it, every suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` behind the screen what it does is try to get **aws-amplify-federatedInfo** from local storage then return based on that. Turning on or off your wifi have nothing to do with clearing your local storage.

I have tried to re-produce it with my side project that also use Oauth from Google and Amplify. It doesn't go away or throw any error in console. This probably have more to do with your local or other piece of code in your application